# Custom React-Color component breaks on updating color

Tags: reactjs, react-color

I'm trying to implement a custom color picker using React-Color and I've hit a snag.

You can see a simplified example of my issue here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-color-multiple-custom-pickers-q0eiq

The initial state comes through correctly but as soon as I try to interact with the components the entire thing explodes. It looks like the new state I'm setting is missing a bunch of the original properties and I have no idea why.

I'm extremely new to React...

**[Edit]**

Updated main link with final working version. Special thanks to @ravibagul91 for helping me work through the problem.

Comment: Hi, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be sending `key` to `onChange` handler to update the appropriate key in the state,

```
<div style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: 0 }}>
    <div style={{
          height: "100px",
          width: "100px",
          position: "relative",
          float: "left",
          zIndex: 1000000
        }}>
        <Saturation hsl={swatch.hsl} hsv={swatch.hsv} onChange={(e)=> handleChange(e, 'hsv')} /> //Provide key to update
    </div>
    <div style={{
          marginLeft: "10px",
          height: "100px",
          width: "10px",
          position: "relative",
          float: "left",
          zIndex: 1000000
        }}>
        <Hue hsl={swatch.hsl} direction="vertical" onChange={(e)=> handleChange(e,'hsl')} /> //Provide key to update
    </div>
    <EditableInput value={swatch.hex} onChange={(e)=> handleChange(e, 'hex')} /> //Provide key to update
</div>
```

Your change handler should be this,

```
const handleChange = (c, key) => {
  setSwatch(l => ({...l , [key]: c}))
};
```

Finally you can watch the change,

```
useEffect (() => {
  console.log(swatch)
},[swatch])
```

Comment: Forked and made a version with the changes you suggested [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-color-multiple-custom-pickers-ooz7u) but while it's now updating all the requisite parts correctly the `color` property that sort of governs them all isn't updating. So the input doesn't update and any hex value I type in doesn't update the others. Guessing there's one more piece missing here?

Comment: Can you provide the forked version also?

Comment: Guess the link didn't come across: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-color-multiple-custom-pickers-ooz7u

Comment: I think you want `hex` and `color` both should get updated on change of the input? Try this `<EditableInput value={swatch.hex} onChange={(e)=> {handleChange(e, 'hex');handleChange(e, 'color')}} />`

Comment: Updates color but with an HSL object, doesn't update the others.

Comment: I think it's getting confusing now, can you explain your exact requirement?

Comment: I think you have added `handleChange(e, 'color')` for all the change handlers, you just need to add it to `EditableInput` and not for others. Keep `Saturation` and `Hue` as suggested earlier.

Comment: That's what I did initially but it's still not giving me the intended result, which makes me think there's something missing in all of this. Following the examples from React-Color it doesn't seem like they're setting all values with each change.

My goal for this is to have a single color I can reuse elsewhere in the UI. Now that single color needs to be updated regardless of if they modify the input, saturation or hue components. Likewise those three should be synced so that updating the input, for example, modifies what's displayed on hue and saturation.

Comment: I suppose I could go and update the entire object (using some library to cross-convert to the necessary colors) but I can't help but feel React-Code is somehow supposed to be doing this for me.

Comment: Marking this correct because you helped me quite a lot in getting to the answer.